# Are there any examples of hyperelastic materials?

Tags: material-science, solid-mechanics

I found the definition of hyperelastic materials, but I can’t find any examples of them.

So, are there any hyperelastic materials in our lives?

Comment: The superelastic metals? There is the wire that is used in bras (those that may get into the filters of laundry machines). Such wire is also used in glasses. It is like memory metal.

Comment: Flexon eyewear it is called in pairs of glasses.

Comment: @Pieter So you mean: hyperelastic (or superelastic?) material can recover from large deformation?

Comment: You asked the question, but if you mean metals, then the largest consumer market for these materials is in underwire bras.

Comment: @Pieter I see. Thank you very much! It's a good example!

Comment: I'm not sure why all the comments so far are discussing metals, but the most common example of a hyperelastic material is rubber as discussed at the following Wikipedia page.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelastic_material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming by "hyperelastic" you mean materials that experience large strains without deforming plastically. Their behavior is difficult to express using common constitutive relationships, and the strain is often expressed in terms of a strain energy function instead.

Rubbers and some other polymers approximate this behavior. Its also an active of research for metamaterials. Hyperelasticity is sometimes combined with viscoelastic material models when simulating biological tissue. An example of using hyperelasticity for such an application is [Mihai et al. "A comparison of hyperelastic constitutive models applicable to brain and fat tissues."](http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/12/110/20150486)

You can find similar approaches for people developing next-generation heart valves with some googling.